# Facebook\WebDriver Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities"} error

Tags: php, google-chrome, selenium, curl, selenium-chromedriver

I try using Selenium and Chromewebdriver with PHP Facebooks Webdriver on a Debian Jessie. I dont know but the Session will not start.

I Installed Java SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode) and Selenium version: '3.9.1', revision: '63f7b50' and ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304).

I i start Selenium with the call `java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver/srv/www/XXXX/build/chromedriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.9.1.jar`

the result seems to be ok for me.

> 06:42:17.240 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.9.1', revision:
>   '63f7b50' 06:42:17.241 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
>   on port 4444 2018-02-09 06:42:17.378:INFO::main: Logging initialized
>   @498ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog 2018-02-09
>   06:42:17.536:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.7.v20170914, build
>   timestamp: 2017-11-21T12:27:37-09:00, git hash:
>   82b8fb23f757335bb3329d540ce37a2a2615f0a8 2018-02-09
>   06:42:17.585:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main:
>   ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3b0143d3{/,null,STARTING}
>   has uncovered http methods for path: / 2018-02-09
>   06:42:17.596:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started
>   o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3b0143d3{/,null,AVAILABLE} 2018-02-09
>   06:42:17.642:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started
>   ServerConnector@596c6acf{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4444} 2018-02-09
>   06:42:17.643:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @763ms 06:42:17.643 INFO -
>   Selenium Server is up and running on port 4444

If I run following PHP Code

```
try{
            $options = new ChromeOptions();
            $options->setBinary("/srv/www/XXXX/build/chromedriver");
            //$options->addArguments(["--headless", "--window-size=571,42"]);

                /*webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging*/

            $caps = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
            $caps->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
            $caps->setPlatform("Linux");
            $host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/';

            $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $caps);

            $driver->get('http://www.ende.de/');
            $driver->quit();

        } catch (\Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
```

As result i get

> Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params:
>   {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"Linux","chromeOptions":{"binary":"/srv/www/XXXX/build/chromedriver","args":["--headless","--window-size=571,42"]}}}
>
> Operation timed out after 30001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

The Server Logs this

> 2018-02-09 06:43:57.988:INFO:osjshC.ROOT:qtp1712536284-9:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet-4501b7af:
>   Initialising WebDriverServlet 06:43:58.109 INFO - Found handler:
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@5d018ae5
>   06:43:58.117 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler:
>   BeginSession) 06:43:58.247 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities
>   {browserName: chrome, chromeOptions: {args: [--headless,
>   --window-size=571,42], binary: /srv/www/XXXX/buil...}, platform: LINUX} 06:43:58.250 INFO - Capabilities {browserName:
>   chrome, chromeOptions: {args: [--headless, --window-size=571,42],
>   binary: /srv/www/XXXX/buil...}, platform: LINUX} matched
>   class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory
>   (provider: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService) Starting
>   ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304) on port 29459 [0.589][WARNING]: PAC support
>   disabled because there is no system implementation Starting
>   ChromeDriver (v2.9.248304) on port 9515 2018-02-09
>   06:44:58.965:WARN:osjs.HttpChannel:qtp1712536284-9: /wd/hub/session
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.EofException     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.setContent(ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.java:91)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.setContent(ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:96)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.handle(WebDriverServlet.java:258)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.doPost(WebDriverServlet.java:161)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.service(WebDriverServlet.java:121)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)  at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)    at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.EofException     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:292)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:429)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:322)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:372)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:800)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:528)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:783)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:834)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:234)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:218)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:535)
>     at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:108)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.setContent(ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.java:89)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.setContent(ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:96)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.handle(WebDriverServlet.java:258)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.doPost(WebDriverServlet.java:161)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.service(WebDriverServlet.java:121)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)  at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)    at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.io.IOException: Broken pipe  at
>   sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)    at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint.flush(ChannelEndPoint.java:270)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.WriteFlusher.flush(WriteFlusher.java:429)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:322)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:372)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection$SendCallback.process(HttpConnection.java:800)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:224)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.send(HttpConnection.java:528)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.sendResponse(HttpChannel.java:783)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.write(HttpChannel.java:834)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:234)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:218)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpOutput.write(HttpOutput.java:535)
>     at com.google.common.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:108)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.setContent(ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.java:89)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.setContent(ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.java:83)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.ExceptionHandler.execute(ExceptionHandler.java:96)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.handle(WebDriverServlet.java:258)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.doPost(WebDriverServlet.java:161)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.service(WebDriverServlet.java:121)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:860)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:190)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)  at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)    at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
>     at
>   org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

I don`t know whats wrong. I tried to install chrome but no effect. It is also not possible to start a chrome session though the Webinterface. I tried different Versions of Chromewebdriver and Selenium as well. Has anybody an idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 6):

If you fix the version compatibility. You need to adjust the PHP Code to this and that works:

```
$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->setBinary("/usr/bin/google-chrome");
$options->addArguments(["--headless","--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox"]);

/*webdriver.chrome.verboseLogging*/

$caps = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$caps->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
$caps->setPlatform("Linux");
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/';

$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $caps);

$driver->get('http://www.ende.de');
var_dump($driver->getTitle());
$driver->quit();
```

Comment: I confirm that this works - I was using Chrome Version 67.0.3396.87 (Official Build) (64-bit) on ubuntu Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with ChromeDriver 2.40.565383 in headless mode without "--disable-gpu", "--no-sandbox" arguments and I was getting all sorts of errors. I added these arguments and `$caps->setPlatform("Linux");` and now it is working again. I don't really know which of these is really responsible.

Answer (score 2):

As per the error stack trace you have provided your main error is :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.EofException at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.setContent(ServletResponseWrappingHttpResponse.java:91)
```

Which implies that a *RuntimeException* occured during handling of *HttpResponse* .

However your main issue is the **version compatibility** among the binaries you are using as follows :

- You are using *chromedriver=v2.9* which is pretty ancient.
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.9*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> **`Supports Chrome v31-34`**

- Your *Chrome Browser* version is unknown to us but possibly *v60.x* as you are trying to use headless.
- You are using *Selenium Version 3.9.1* .
- Your *JDK version* is unknown to us.

So there is a clear mismatch between the *ChromeDriver* version (*v2.33*) and the matching requirement of *Chrome Browser* version (*v60-62*)

### Solution

- Upgrade `JDK` to  recent levels **`JDK Version 8 Update 151`**.
- Upgrade `Selenium` to  current levels **`Version 3.9.1`**.
- Upgrade `ChromeDriver` to  **`ChromeDriver v2.35`** level.
- Keep `Chrome Browser` to  **`v64.x`** levels. ([*as per ChromeDriver v2.35 release notes*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt))
- Incase your *Chrome Browser* base version is older, try to uninstall *Chrome Browser* through [Revo Uninstaller](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install the required recent GA released version of the *Chrome Browser* .
- Clear the *Browser Cache* before your *Test Excution* .
- Run [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool before and after execution of your *Test Suites* .
- Execute your `Test`.

Comment: The chrome Version is already 64.0 but the Chromedriver version was not correct. I Installed the ChromeDriver v2.35. But that wasnt the hole solution.

Comment: @PatrickMüssig did you ever figure out a solution? I'm getting the same error...if so can you add as an answer?

Comment: yes I added the solution as new post here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709637/facebook-webdriver-curl-error-thrown-for-http-post-to-session-with-params/48713692#48713692)