# This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 75 error with Selenium ChromeDriver and Chrome through facebook/php-webdriver

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, facebook-php-webdriver

I'm using selenium, chromedriver, facebook/php-webdriver
But the server always hang after an error
What could be the problem? selenium or php?

here is the php error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"w3c":false,"binary":"","args":["--no-sandbox","--headless","--disable-gpu"]}}} Operation timed out after 51627 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received in /var/www/html/php-selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:297 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/php-selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(144): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand)) #1 /var/www/html/php-selenium/s.php(19): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhos...', Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities), 50000, 50000) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/php-selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php on line 297
```

from selenium log:

```
[1561345982.225][WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 75.
    03:13:06.892 WARN - Exception thrown
    org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:32.194Z'
    System info: host: 'shadowsocks-server', ip: '10.140.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_212'
    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

Version Info:

- ChromeDriver 2.35.528139
- Chrome --version Google Chrome 75.0.3770.80

+++++++++++++++++++++

updated June 29th, I have updated chromdriver to 75.0.3770.90, but the problem still persists. nothing changes.

+++++++++++++++++++++ June 30th,2019

I have solved this, with "top" command, I saw a progress whose name was kswapd0 consumed too much CPU. It is a progress which is related to swap, so I add this line to /etc/sysctl.conf:
vm.swappiness=5
and got more RAM, the service has been running for a day. and no hanging any more.
I didn't realize that 1.8GB RAM was not enough for chrome with default configration.

Comment: `[WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 75.`  What versions of chrome and chromedriver are you running?

Comment: Hi orde,  
Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 
 chrome --version
Google Chrome 75.0.3770.80

Comment: Please [edit the question](/posts/56729580/edit) to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: `chrome` and `chromedriver.exe` are mismatched: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads.  The concise instructions should point you...

Answer (score 1):

This php error message...

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"w3c":false,"binary":"","args":["--no-sandbox","--headless","--disable-gpu"]}}} Operation timed out after 51627 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received in /var/www/html/php-selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php:297 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/php-selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.php(144): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\HttpCommandExecutor->execute(Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\WebDriverCommand)) #1 /var/www/html/php-selenium/s.php(19): Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver::create('http://localhos...', Object(Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities), 50000, 50000) #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/php-selenium/vendor/facebook/webdriver/lib/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.php on line 297
```

and this selenium error message...

```
[WARNING]: This version of ChromeDriver has not been tested with Chrome version 75.
03:13:06.892 WARN - Exception thrown
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to initiate/spawn a new **WebBrowser** i.e. **Chrome Browser** session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.35*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- You are using *chrome=75.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v75.0*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome version 75**

So there is a clear mismatch between *ChromeDriver v2.35* and the *Chrome Browser v75.0*

---

### Solution

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.75**](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=75.0.3770.90/) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v75*** level. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.75 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/75.0.3770.8/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.

---

### Outro

- [Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {“desiredCapabilities”:{“browserName”:“chrome”,“platform”:“ANY” with Selenium and PHPUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54752626/curl-error-thrown-for-http-post-to-session-with-params-desiredcapabilities/54754378#54754378)
- [Facebook\WebDriver Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {“desiredCapabilities”} error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709637/facebook-webdriver-curl-error-thrown-for-http-post-to-session-with-params-de/48711163#48711163)

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have installed the new chromedriver. chromedriver -v
ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.90,  the service is still not stable. always thrown "Operation timed out after 50000 milliseconds with 0 out of -1 bytes received", "tab crashed" etc. However, it is better than before because it doesn't crash the server

Comment: @LeeBill Nice to hear _it is better than before_. For the error `tab crashed` see this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53902507/unknown-error-session-deleted-because-of-page-crash-from-unknown-error-cannot/53970825#53970825).